# How to avoid loss of DB when changing Grails domain class in development

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.0

One of the advantages of Grails 2.0 is that you can change domain classes in development without needing to restart the application server. This works, however when I change domain classes I lose all my bootstrap data, which basically defeats the purpose. I'm using the default h2 database.

What is the best way to get around this? Do I have to go to an external DB like Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `DataSource.groovy` in a newly-created Grails 2 app has

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
```

The `create-drop` means the database will be re-created from scratch whenever the application restarts.  If you want a database that persists across restarts then change this to something like

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
}
```

(i.e. change `create-drop` to `update` and remove the `:mem` from the `url`).  However note that not all changes you can make to a domain class can be reflected in the limited schema changes that `update` can apply.  Adding properties should be OK, but removing properties or making changes to the constraints that affect schema generation may require you to drop and re-create the database anyway (stop the app, delete the devDb files and start it up again).

Comment: OK, thanks. The thing is when you modify e.g. a Service class, the app doesn't need to restart. But evidently modifying a Domain class forces some kind of restart - enough to drop the DB but not to run Bootstrap again. I guess if I want to maintain the create-drop behaviour I could move the logic from Bootstrap to another class and then script this to be run on restart via an Event or so.